# how to convert bytes to binary and return back the bytes

Tags: python, binary, byte, converters

so I try to change the bytes to binary and get the bytes again. but when I check, the result I got was different. can someone fix it so I can get the same result?

```
def bytestobiner(password):
    print(password)
    li = []
    for my_byte in password:
        if my_byte != None:
            # string_output = ' '.join(f'{my_byte:0>8b}' for my_byte in password)
            string_output = ' '.join('{:08b}'.format(x) for x in bytearray(password))
            li.append(string_output)
    
            return li, len(string_output.split(' '))

def binertobytes(f):
    print("biner bytes")
    print(f)
    hasil = bytes([int(f[i:i+8], 2) for i in range(0, len(f), 8)])
    return hasil
```

i need li to count how many binary was there.

the password bytes i was input : `b'QH5da48yXx7DGPdhRGPqIUHZOv7HXyPI7oKlaApNV3Y='`
but what i get was `b'\xa2\x90j\xc8\xc2hp\xf2\xb0\xf0n\x88\x8e\xa0\xc8\xd0\xa4\x8e\xa0\xe2\x92\xaa\x90\xb4\x9e\xecn\x90\xb0\xf2\xa0\x92n\xde\x96\xd8\xc2\x82\xe0\x9c\xacf\xb2='`

i want get `b'QH5da48yXx7DGPdhRGPqIUHZOv7HXyPI7oKlaApNV3Y='` again

the result i get from bytestobinary:

```
01010001 01001000 00110101 01100100 01100001 00110100 00111000 01111001 01011000 01111000 00110111 01000100 01000111 01010000 01100100 01101000 01010010 01000111 01010000 01110001 01001001 01010101 01001000 01011010 01001111 01110110 00110111 01001000 01011000 01111001 01010000 01001001 00110111 01101111 01001011 01101100 01100001 01000001 01110000 01001110 01010110 00110011 01011001 00111101
```

and the f i get from binarytobytes: `101000101001000001101010110010001100001001101000011100001111001010110000111100000110111010001000100011101010000011001000110100001010010010001110101000001110001010010010101010101001000010110100100111101110110001101110100100001011000011110010101000001001001001101110110111101001011011011000110000101000001011100000100111001010110001100110101100100111101`

the 0 was gone. how to keep the 0?

Comment: Probably a typo when reentering the reverse function (Hint the spaces are a nuisance from output of bytestobiner). As is, your code is correct I.e i was able to reobtain the 'password'

Comment: oh i was read again the binary result, but there's different. the different func from bytestobinary has "011" in front. but at func binarytobyes, the "0" isn't any, just "11". how if i want get infront have 0 in func binarytobyes? @JasonChia

Comment: Look up bitpadding. I think str.zfill() will help you out here.

Comment: it's not work, its add if you now the len of binary @JasonChia

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify. I do not see where in your code its going so wrong?

Here is what I run to test:

```
def bytestobiner(password):
    print(password)
    li = []
    for my_byte in password:
        if my_byte != None:
            # string_output = ' '.join(f'{my_byte:0>8b}' for my_byte in password)
            string_output = ' '.join('{:08b}'.format(x) for x in bytearray(password))
            li.append(string_output)
    
            return li, len(string_output.split(' '))

def binertobytes(f):
    print("biner bytes")
    print(f)
    hasil = bytes([int(f[i:i+8], 2) for i in range(0, len(f), 8)])
    return hasil

initial_pass = b'QH5da48yXx7DGPdhRGPqIUHZOv7HXyPI7oKlaApNV3Y='
val = bytestobiner(initial_pass)
val 
--> (['01010001 01001000 00110101 01100100 01100001 00110100 00111000 01111001 01011000 01111000 00110111 01000100 01000111 01010000 01100100 01101000 01010010 01000111 01010000 01110001 01001001 01010101 01001000 01011010 01001111 01110110 00110111 01001000 01011000 01111001 01010000 01001001 00110111 01101111 01001011 01101100 01100001 01000001 01110000 01001110 01010110 00110011 01011001 00111101'], 44)
reformatted_val = val[0][0].replace(' ','')
returned_pass = binertobytes(reformatted_val)
returned_pass 
--> b'QH5da48yXx7DGPdhRGPqIUHZOv7HXyPI7oKlaApNV3Y='
returned_pass == initial_pass
--> True
```

As can be seen...the initial password is returnned by the very functions you use. So I really do not see what you are finding wrong.